# WP7 - Scrolling ListBox in external ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have the following page layout in my application:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
      Grid.Row="1">

  <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer1" 
                MaxHeight="600"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel1" >
      <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" />

      <toolkit:ListPicker  x:Name="ListPicker1" />

      <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock2" />

      <TextBox x:Name="TextBlock3" />

      <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock4" />

      <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel2" >

        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock5" />

        <Image x:Name="Image1"/>

      </StackPanel>

      <ListBox x:Name="ListBox1">
        <!--Customize the ListBox template to remove the built-in ScrollViewer-->
        <ListBox.Template>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <ItemsPresenter />
          </ControlTemplate>
        </ListBox.Template>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>

            <!-- .... -->

          </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                    Value="Stretch" />
          </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      </ListBox>

    </StackPanel>

  </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

I added an external `ScrollViewer` instead of the using the `ListBox`'s because without it the stuff above the `ListBox` was taking too much room and not leaving enough space to view the `ListBox` contents.

Now, the problem is if I add an item to the end of the `ListBox` the `ScrollIntoView` method does not work. So I need to use the `ScrollViewer`'s `ScrollToVerticalOffset` method.

I'm adding the new item to an `ObservableCollection` that is bound to the `ListBox` when the user clicks a button on the application bar. How can I calculate the value to be passed to `ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the container that the ListBox has generated to host your element. Once you have this container, you can find its position relative to the scrollviewer:

```
  var newItem = // the item you just added to your listbox

  // find the ListBox container
  listBox.UpdateLayout()
  var element = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(newItem) as FrameworkElement;

  // find its position in the scroll viewer
  var transform = element.TransformToVisual(ScrollViewer);
  var elementLocation = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
  double newVerticalOffset = elementLocation.Y + ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;

  // scroll into view
  ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(newVerticalOffset);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you so much! I did have to use `myListBox.UpdateLayout();` before this code, otherwise `ContainerFromItem()` kept returning `null`. Also, the result of `ContainerFromItem()` needs to be cast to a `ListBoxItem`.